# Retrieve JWT token in angular from Restful API in Symfony

Tags: angular, jwt

I really need your help, I'm trying for one week to retrieve my JWT token created with my API Symfony in my front but my token is always null.
This token works in the API, I can make the authorization with "Bearer token".
How can I get the value of the token in angular?
My component :

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { TokenStorageService } from '../token-storage.service';

//import jquery for modifying materialize
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './home-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeLoginComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private tokenStorage: TokenStorageService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({
        indicators: false
      });
      autoplay();
      function autoplay() {
        $('.carousel').carousel('next');
        setTimeout(autoplay, 4000);
      }
    });

  }

  onSubmit(username: string, password: string) {
    this.authService.login(username, password)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.tokenStorage.saveToken(data.accessToken);
        this.tokenStorage.saveUser(data);
      })
  }
}
```

My form :

```
 <div class="col s12 m12 l12 xl6" id="formConnexion">

            <form [formGroup]="formGroup">

                <p id="cardTitle" class="center #004d40 teal darken-3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Connexion</p>
                <!-- USERNAME -->
                <label>Identifiant</label>
                <input type="text" #username formControlName="username" class="form-control">
                <!-- PASSWORD -->
                <label>Mot de passe</label>
                <input type="password" #password formControlName="password" class="form-control">
                <!-- SUBMIT -->
                <button (click)="onSubmit(username.value, password.value)" class="btn btn-lg #004d40 teal darken-3">
                    Se connecter
                </button>
                <a id="forgotten" href="#" class="dark-text darken-text-2">Mot de passe oublié?</a>

            </form>
        </div>
```

My auth-service :

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

  // URL to web api
  private loginUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    console.log(localStorage);
    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, { username, password })
      .pipe(tap(
        res => {
          localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.access_token);
        }
      ))
  }
}
```

My interceptor :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, finalize, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TokenStorageService } from './token-storage.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';


@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private token: TokenStorageService, private authService: AuthService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
    request = request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set( 'Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
    });
    console.log(request);

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: First, I would check the chrome developer tool and see if the request is sent and if yes, what raw response you see. What does the response include?

Comment: I don't know how to do it properly, but the value of the  token is null

Comment: Your stored local storage item name is `access_token`, But you tried to retrieve that from `acces_token`

Comment: ok I changed thta but I have still the same issue

Comment: Change `const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('access_token'));` to `const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');` and try.

Comment: try to use google developer and get the result bro